# Internet Explorer and Firefox alignment elements differently on site

Tags: html, internet-explorer, layout

When [my site](http://www.mathstutors4me.co.uk/index.php) is rendered in Firefox, the text "Find A Maths Tutor" is directly above the text "Private Maths Tutor":

[image: Firefox rendering]

This is how I want it.

When the same page is rendered in Internet Explorer, the text "Find a Maths Tutor" is above but to the left of "Private Maths Tutor":

[image: Internet Explorer rendering]

How can I have the "Find A Maths Tutor" element the same way in Internet Explorer as it is in Firefox?

Comment: IE prior 9 handle CSS in its own manner. They have stupid behaviour. To get things right, you need to add some IE hack in the CSS. I would suggest you to post this question in SO or ask a moderator to migrate it.

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay - IE9 is only better than IE8 which isn't saying much.

Answer (score 9):

There is a comment before doctype in your markup:

```
<!--- start of common-head-and-right.php        -->
```

This causes that Internet Explorer renders your website in quirks mode, with behaviour similar to IE5. Remove the comment, `<!doctype>` must be the first thing in your markup.